# Vader for testing plugin that eases window navigation

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, plugin-development, unit-testing

Some time ago I wrote [a plugin for easy window navigation](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ), and now I was trying to write some test for it, using [Vader](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim), which I knew nothing about until a few hours ago.

Basically, with my plugin active, once you press <kbd>leader</kbd> (which for me is set to <kbd>space</kbd>), all following keys are interpreted as you had hit <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> beforehand. <kbd>Escape</kbd> can be used to exit this "window navigation mode".

Despite I had never used Vader, that plugin is fairly usable, so I could write a test in short time:

```
Given vim (Empty file is enough):

Do (split vertically, move right, split horizontally, move down):
  \<space>wvlsj\<esc>

Execute (Current win is the expected position in the layout):
  AssertEqual win_getid(), winlayout()[1][1][1][1][1]

Do (Close 2 of the 3 windows):
  \<space>wqq\<esc>

Execute (Last window standing):
  AssertEqual winlayout()[0], 'leaf'
  AssertEqual winlayout()[1], win_getid()
```

which kinda gives the correct result (the test passes), ***but not before I see the outcoming layout and the message***

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and only after I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, do I see the result:

```
Starting Vader: 1 suite(s), 4 case(s)
  Starting Vader: /home/enrico/.vim/plugged/WinZoZ/test/winzoz.vader
    (1/4) [     DO] split vertically, move right, split horizontally, move down
    (2/4) [EXECUTE] Current win is the expected position in the layout
    (3/4) [     DO] Close 2 of the 3 windows
    (4/4) [EXECUTE] Last window standing
  Success/Total: 4/4
Success/Total: 4/4 (assertions: 3/3)
Elapsed time: 0.25 sec.
```

The strange behavior described above already made me think something is wrong.

However, I don't know if the problem is in my plugin or in my usage of Vader, and I'd like some help to understand what's going on.

---

When I was choosing the tags for this question, I noticed the existence of [plugin-vim-test](/questions/tagged/plugin-vim-test), which points to [vim-test](https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test), which I have never heard of. Maybe I should give it a try.

Comment: How are you invoking the tests? If you run the same commands manually, do you get a similar prompt?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I run `:Vader test/winzoz.vader`.

Comment: Ok, @D.BenKnoble, I suspect what you were alluding too. Running it from the shell via `vi '+Vader!relarive/path/to/test.vader' && echo Success || echo Failure` indeed reports success. However, I think the point still remains as to why my plugin seems to require that one presses enter.